# Clear a form and populate jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, loops

I am trying to clear a form and then repopulate it with new data. I have a page that has a list of search histories, along with a "search again" button, when clicked, it takes that search history string, split it, then match those again all the various form items; checkbox, radio, etc. The form has basically every kind of form element in it and everything is populating like I want it to except the checkboxes. The first time I click the populate form button, it works fine, but after the first click all the checkboxes start going haywire...some items populating like they should, some not, in a strange random pattern. I have not included the html because I don't think it is necessary but if anyone needs more info, please let me know.

This resets the form. I have tested this independently and it works.

```
function form_reset(){
   $('#hosp_search_form')[0].reset();
   $('#hosp_search_form').find("input[type=text], textarea").val("");
   $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(){
      $('input[type=checkbox]').removeAttr('checked');
   });
   $('input[type=number]').val('');
   $('input[type=radio]').each(function(){
   $(this).removeAttr('checked');
 });
```

On click, first clear the form of previous values, then grab the other needed values and format them...this part gets a little ugly in sections but I have consoled out all the values and everything is how it should be.

```
$('.search_again_btn').on('click', function(){
  form_reset();
   $('#hosp_search_form').find('input[type=checkbox]').removeAttr('checked');
   var id = $(this).data('id');
   var searchstring = $('#searchstring_' + id).text();
   var patientcode = $('#patientcode_' + id).text();
   var mrn = $('#mrn_' + id).text();
 var first_name = patientcode.substr(0,2);
 var last_name = patientcode.substr(2,2);
 var age = patientcode.substr(4,3);
 var gender = patientcode.substr(6,2);
 var age = age.replace(/\D+/g, '');
 gender = gender.replace(/[0-9]/g, '');
```

Populates some of the form, works fine

```
 //populate fields in search form
 $('input[name=fn]').val(first_name);
 $('input[name=ln]').val(last_name);
 $('input[name=patientage]').val(age);
 $('input[name=mrn]').val(mrn);
```

Populate another part of the form, also always works as needed

```
 //populate gender fields
 if(gender == 'F'){
   $('.female').attr('checked', 'checked');
 }
 if(gender == 'M'){
   $('.male').attr('checked', 'checked');
 }
```

Here is where I suspect the issue is. splitsearch is a long string (a previous search history) with items separated by a . and they get split into separate items. I console logged this, it correctly breaking it into the smaller values like I need, then iterate through those and iterate through all the checkboxes which each have a data attr holding values that can be in the splitsearch. If a value matches, it should make it checked. This works every time the first time, for any combo of splitsearch/search string values, but after the first time, I don't know what it is doing. I expect that each click, the form is cleared and it does the value matching again as I described.

```
 //populate checkboxes
 var splitsearch = searchstring.split('. ');
 $.each(splitsearch, function(key, value){
   $('input[type=checkbox').each(function(keyb, checkbox){
       item = $(checkbox).data('services');
       if(item == value){
           $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
           console.log($(this));
    }
 });
```

This is doing the same as the above but works every time...probably because there is never multiple combinations like with checkboxes.

```
$('input[name=payor]').each(function(k, radio){
 if(value == $(radio).data('payors')){
   $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
   //console.log($(this));
  }
});
```

Also like the above and works.

```
$('input[name=bedtype]').each(function(keyc, radio){
bed = $(radio).data('bed');
  if(bed == value){
    $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
  }
});
```

This part below is quite ugly but is populating the form like I need every time.

```
 //if searchstring contains Needs Transportation, returns true, else     returns false 

 if(value.indexOf("Needs Transportation") > -1 === true){
   $('.transyes').attr('checked', 'checked');
 }
 if(value.indexOf("Near hospital") > -1 != true){
   $('input[name=desiredzip]').val(searchstring.substr(5,5));
 }
 if(value.indexOf("5 mile radius") > -1 === true){
   $('.miles_5').attr('checked', 'checked');
 }
 if(value.indexOf("10 mile radius") > -1 === true){
    $('.miles_10').attr('checked', 'checked');
 }
 if(value.indexOf("15 mile radius") > -1 === true){
    $('.miles_15').attr('checked', 'checked');
 }
 if(value.indexOf("20 mile radius") > -1 === true){
   $('.miles_20').attr('checked', 'checked');
  }
});
```

Scrolls the window up to the populated search form and show it.

```
   window.scrollTo(0,100);
   $('#search_show').show();
});
```

Comment: This post is far too long....need to scale it down to minimal and verifiable example and scale down thos text blocks to just highlights

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a thought but, it might help you to restructure your code a bit to keep it DRY.

```
// used to Hold search data in local or global
var data;

function form_reset() {
  // clear form
}
function get_search_data() {
  // populate data with search results
}
function form_populate() {
  // use data to populate form
}

$('.search_again_btn').on('click', function(){
  get_search_data();
  form_reset(); 
  form_populate();
});

// Initial Load of form
get_search_data();
form_populate();
```

that way you use the same population function initially as you do when you refresh and it forces you to put your data into a variable that can be seen in both the clear and populate functions removing your reliance on this and $(this).

also you need to bear in mind that the value of  this  inside a click function is going to be in the context of the click event itself and not the JavaScript object that the rest of your code belongs to.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Yes, that above script is a mess. Also found that I should have been using .prop for checked not .attr. I will post the final script once I finish it.

Comment: In get_search_data(), what would be the best way to add the data to var data? I am thinking in the form of an associative array...

Comment: Correction - apparently there are no associative arrays in js (I am more of a php developer), looks like I can create an object? That way I can basically add labels to the different datas like an associative array. ...this is what I am trying to do. Let me know if there is a better approach. Thank you.